# How to supply auxiliary power?

Tags: circuit-design

I just ordered an electronics hobbyist kit. It comes with a breadboard and a bunch of other components. Looking forward to work on my first project.

In my setup, an external device is connected to the PC via USB. One of the pins on the USB provides +5V to the device.

I need to keep the external device alive even when the PC is not on. Essentially, I need a battery backup circuit that kicks in as soon as the PC power is turned off.

Note that the external device can even take +1V to be kept alive. Ideally, I would like to send minimum current in order to keep the battery alive for a longer time.

Wondering if you can point me in the right direction. Is there even a name for such a circuit? Regards.

Comment: So you want low voltage at that port if the USB disconnects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Construct a simple circuit with your added source. I will edit an explanation of how it works later today
[image: The Circuit]

Edit: As suggested by colin shottky diodes would be very useful as there is less voltage drop.

Comment: Might be worth suggesting shottky diodes, else the Vf would make the 1.5v rail too low to be of use if the receiving device needs 1v.

Comment: True. Didn't think about that point.

Comment: It is in effect "ORring" the supplies.

Comment: What do you mean? The 1.5V diode will be in reverse bias as long as 5v is present making the 1.5v use no voltage at all. If 5v disconnects then 1.5v can flow freely

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you very much for your help. Looking forward to your explanation. One quick question. How does the circuit guarantee that my battery is not getting used when 5v supply is on?

Comment: As written above we know that a diode only conducts when there is a forward bias right? If you have 5V on then it will be at backwards bias and in other words the diode will block the voltage as long as the 5V is there. You can use any voltage less than 5V instead of 1.5V there

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Now it makes complete sense. Regards.

Comment: If the answer helped you feel free to select it as the selected answer, Thanks!